# LINQPAD - Extension Method to run statement every X seconds

Tags: linqpad

I've got an idea for a fun little extension method in LINQPad but it's stumping me on how to do it.

Basically I'd like an extension method that I can add at the end of any LINQPad statement to make that statement execute every X seconds.

So, for example, I'd do something like this:
   "Hello World".Dump().RunEvery(5);

And this would execute "Hello World".Dump() every 5 seconds.  The result of that would be Hello World dumping to the screen every 5 seconds.

I'd like it to be flexible enough so any statement that executes in LINQPad can run on a timer.  This would be useful for queries I run of EventLog tables so I don't have to run them manually as often as I do.  I could just keep flipping back to the window and know what I'm seeing is the latest.

I'm thinking this involves C# reflection and timers, but I'm struggling putting it together.  Also, since Dump is a LINQPad extension method itself, the syntax might have to be different so it's like:
     "Hello World".RunEvery(5).Dump();

Anyway, let me know if you have ideas or have done something like this.  I'd really like to stop having to hit F5 all the time!

Comment: Use Rx and it will be trivial.

Comment: Could you work up an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Rx, you could do something like this:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ForEach(_ =>
{
    "Hello World".Dump();
});
```

Consider using a `DumpContainer` so you don't spam your result window with each and every result.

```
var container = new DumpContainer().Dump();
var i = 0; // just to show the difference
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ForEach(_ =>
{
    container.Content = "Hello World" + i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.  I watched a few Rx tutorials and was kind of lost.

Comment: Ok, this works for the intended purpose.  The dump container is more appropriate for my purposes because I'm not just spitting out one row it's a table of data.  However, the dump container dumps the HTML view and not the data grid view that I like when I run my statement outside it.  Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think the grid view was intended to dynamically update.  You'll have to stick to the rich text views or come up with a custom visualizer.